# Tooltip not displaying in SVG (using ECMAScript)

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, ecmascript-6, tooltip

I'm working on trying to embed ECMAScript into XML. I found [this tutorial](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/script.html) online. I tried their code locally to confirm it worked, and then tried to build off of that to create tooltip functionality.

In the end, this was my code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="6cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 600 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <!-- ECMAScript to change the radius with each click -->
  <script type="application/ecmascript"> <![CDATA[
        function showTooltip(evt, text) {
            let tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
            tooltip.innerHTML = text;
            tooltip.style.display = "block";
            tooltip.style.left = evt.pageX + 10 + 'px';
            tooltip.style.top = evt.pageY + 10 + 'px';
        }
        function hideTooltip() {
            var tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip"); 
            tooltip.style.display = "none";
        }
  ]]> </script>

  <!-- Outline the drawing area with a blue line -->
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="598" height="498" fill="none" stroke="blue"/>

  <!-- Act on each click event -->
  <circle onmousemove="showTooltip(evt, 'some text')" onmouseout="hideTooltip()" cx="300" cy="225" r="100"
          fill="red"/>

  <text x="300" y="480" 
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" text-anchor="middle">

    Hover over circle for tooltip
  </text>
</svg>
```

But the tooltip functionality didn't work -- nothing happens when you hover over the circle.

I'm a little confused why it's not working -- after all, the only major change was the function being called.

Here's what I tried:

- Emulated the tooltip logic in plain HTML, and it worked
- kept their tutorial code javascript function, but changed the onclick attribute to onmouseover, which worked

Based on that, I think it's something to do with the way I'm calling showTooltip, but I'm not sure what exactly it is. Would appreciate some help debugging and fixing the issue :D

Comment: There's no element with id="tooltip".

Answer (score 0):

Just add a DIV element with "tooltip" ID to your document.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="6cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 600 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <!-- ECMAScript to change the radius with each click -->
  <script type="application/ecmascript"> <![CDATA[
        function showTooltip(evt, text) {
            let tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");
            tooltip.innerHTML = text;
            tooltip.style.display = "block";
            tooltip.style.left = evt.pageX + 10 + 'px';
            tooltip.style.top = evt.pageY + 10 + 'px';
        }
        function hideTooltip() {
            var tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip"); 
            tooltip.style.display = "none";
        }
  ]]> </script>

  <!-- Outline the drawing area with a blue line -->
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="598" height="498" fill="none" stroke="blue"/>

  <!-- Act on each click event -->
  <circle onmousemove="showTooltip(evt, 'some text')" onmouseout="hideTooltip()" cx="300" cy="225" r="100"
          fill="red"/>

  <text x="300" y="480" 
        font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" text-anchor="middle">

    Hover over circle for tooltip
  </text>
</svg>
<div id="tooltip" style="position: absolute; left: 300px; top: 300px"></div>
```